# d3.js - How can I expand force directed graph horizontally?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I'm working on a node graph in d3 (seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/u56Tr/1) The graph itself is quite circular (links/nodes spread out relatively equally in all directions) - how would I make this fit better in a 16:9 window? I assume I'd have to expand the x,y positions of the elements but I can't quite get it right.

Relevant D3 code:

```
force.on("tick", function() {
link.attr("x1", function(d) {
    return d.source.x;
})
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
    });
node_bg.attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
})
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });
node.attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x - (d.group > 0 ? 24 : 32);
})
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return d.y - (d.group > 0 ? 24 : 32);
    });

});
```

Comment: It might be possible to do what you want using methods from multi-foci force layout examples (just Google that phrase), but for your situation, this could just end up fighting the force layout, producing unexpected, quirky results.  (I tried something like that once.)  So I think Lars Kotthoff is right about the force layout.  However, you might want to look at the [cola layout](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/).  I've never tried it, but it looks like it would make it easier to do what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the force layout is to automatically lay out a graph like this so that you don't have to specify the positions of the nodes yourself. How it does that is largely affected by the connections between the nodes. The graph you have doesn't lend itself very well to being laid out in a wide screen format because of its high connectivity -- that is, many nodes are connected to many other nodes. If you were to stretch the graph, some links would become much longer than others and some nodes would be much closer together than others -- this is exactly what the force layout prevents.

You can of course manually "hack" the layout to achieve what you want -- you could, for example, specify different link distances/strengths for each link so that the ones you want to be larger are weaker. Similarly, you could specify a charge function that assigns a weaker repulsion charge to the nodes you want to be closer together.

However, for all of this you would need a pretty good idea of what you want the graph to look like when finished. It would probably be easier to ditch the force layout altogether and simply specify the positions of the nodes yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help - I should take a better look at how I want the end result to look as you said. I probably do want the forced layout after all.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily squeeze diagram to fit 16:9 better.

9/16 is `.5625`. In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/Wt6Wv/) you just look for lines that contain `.5625`, thats all you need to get your diagram squeezed.

And in this another [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VividD/pr784/) you can see your diagram completely smashed, with smaller constant. :) .

Since diagram has a little chaotic look, maybe the good constant for your case would be around 0.4. that way it will fit 16:9 with more certainty.

Comment: This assumes that the default layout is a square, which is not the case. In particular, the size affects initial placement and gravity forces. While this approach may work for this particular example, it won't in general -- in cases where the graph is actually amenable to be stretched out (e.g. a string of nodes), this will squeeze the nodes into the top part of the graph.

Comment: @Lars Could you elaborate more on "squeezing nodes into the top part"? My example does not manipulate vertical dimension. Can you provide working example illustrating your statement?

Comment: Consider [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt6Wv/8/) with two nodes and without squeezing. The nodes are in the middle of the layout. Now consider [the same example with squeezing](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt6Wv/9/). The nodes are pushed into the top part of the SVG, with the bottom part empty. This is what I mean. Essentially what you're doing is forcing a part of the SVG (in this case 1 - 0.5625 of the y dimension) to be empty as the highest y coordinate is mapped to a maximum below it by the multiplication. It's as if you were applying a scale to the coordinates.