# position nodes in force layout graph vertically

Tags: svg, d3.js, d3-force-directed, d3-force

I read a couple of posts on position nodes in force layout but didn't find an answer to what I was looking for.

I have an object with nodes and links.

I' trying to create a graph which would show all the nodes top to bottom.
I was looking at the example code from here:

https://github.com/danielstern/force-graph-example

Here's a screenshot of the result:

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to **position each node** so the nodes without parents would be on the top and the ones connecting to them would be under them and so forth.

Here's an image to illustrate it:

[image]

Right now, all the nodes are scattered randomly.

I wanted to if I need to actually calculate the position of each node in a vertical view or is there a smarter/built-in way to achieve it.

I looked at this example which looked promising:

[How to organise node positions in D3 Force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851634/how-to-organise-node-positions-in-d3-force-layout)

But in my case I don't have a way to differentiate between nodes levels so I don't think the yPostion would help.

I was also looking at thes post:

[d3.js - How can I expand force directed graph horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006761/d3-js-how-can-i-expand-force-directed-graph-horizontally)

According to @Lars Kotthoff:
"The point of the force layout is to automatically lay out a graph like this so that you don't have to specify the positions of the nodes yourself".

Since my graph is not really a tree, I don't think the tree view would match.

What would be my best approach to position the nodes?

Or perhaps there's a better library to achieve what I need?

Comment: I think you might be be better off starting with d3's tree layout.

Comment: @SmokeyShakers - but the 2nd image doesn't look like a real tree - it can also have nodes that point to to nodes at the same level and to the level below or number of root nodes

Answer (score 0):

I found this package:

[d3-dag](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-dag)

It basically supports what I need:

"Often data sets are hierarchical, but are not in a tree structure..."

Here's an exmaple:

[exmaple](https://observablehq.com/@erikbrinkman/d3-dag-sugiyama)